# Evento click se multiplicando

Tags: javascript, eventos

Tenho um sistema de listagem de diretório que exibe arquivos e pastas, quando clico em um item, ele exibe um menu (único) que já fica definido na página e pode ser usado por todos os arquivos. Nesse menu, tem uma opção chamada DELETE, o problema está aí. Para abrir o menu tem que dar um click, entretanto, preciso saber qual foi o id do arquivo escolhido para utilizar na função deleteFile:

```js
var files = document.getElementsByClassName("backgroundFiles");
for(i=0;i<files.length;i++){
    files[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
        menuFiles(this.id, event.clientX, event.clientY);
        deleteFile(this.id);
    });
}
```

Na função deleteFile existe outro evento de click que será acionado quando o usuário clicar em na opção DELETE do menu:

```js
function deleteFile(idElement){
    document.getElementById("a_dele").addEventListener("click", function(event){
        var chave = prompt("Digite a chave de segurança");
        ...
    });
}
```

O problema é que esses eventos estão se multiplicando, ao dar o primeiro clique tudo está ok, já no segundo, aparece duas vezes o prompt, no terceiro clique aparece três vezes o prompt e assim sucessivamente. Alguém poderia me ajudar com uma solução?

Comment: Tentar colocar  event.stoppropagation() na função do clique, isso serve para o clique não se propagar no site.

Comment: Isso ocorre quando você executa `addEventListener` bastantes vezes. Caso você esteja executando esse `for` toda vez que clica no *menu*, está aí o erro.

Comment: Então, já tentei fazer isso tanto com o stopPropagation() quanto com o stopImmediatePropagation() mas sem sucesso. Quanto ao for, ele só é executado uma única vez a cada requisição de diretório, caso eu venha dar um duplo clique em uma pasta para abrir, esse for será refeito novamente só que para arquivos novos.

Comment: A função `delete` devia ser chamada de dentro de `menuFiles`. Podes mostrar o código de `menuFiles`?

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema trocando addEventListener() por onclick() dentro de deleteFile, não sei se seria a forma correta mas está funcionando normalmente. Obrigado a todos pela atenção.